# Resize DataGrid to fit all rows

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datagrid

Some time ago I needed to resize `WinForms DataGridView` that it fits all rows. I mean without vertical `ScrollBar`. Code below:

```
var sum = i.ColumnHeadersHeight;

foreach (DataGridViewRow j in i.Rows) 
{
    sum += j.Height;
}

i.Height = sum;
```

Now I need to obtain similar effect in `WPF DataGrid`. Any ideas?

Comment: What's your use case exactly ? There are many ways to achieve this and it can depend on the container.

Comment: I have number of DataGrids placed one after another vertically. Each of them has variable number of rows. The goal is to display all rows from all DataGrids in way that next DataGrid top posistion is previous DataGrid bottom position + margin.

Comment: Il you put them in a ListBox, this will be the edfault behavior.